# Im having issues using python numpy.std() for a nested list to filter out the irrelevant data?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an incoming list with many different variations:

```
[(float)Width, (float)Height, aspect ratio, unique name]
[(float)Width, (float)Height, aspect ratio, unique name]
```

I'm trying to figure out how to first run standard deviation to filter out with the area using the width and height, then rerun another level and filter out with the aspect ratio. In the end, I'm planning to generate the mean of the width and height [np.mean(w_h, axis = 0)]. I'm seeing that I will need to separate the lists but I want to make sure that if it is outside the expected values I can remove it for the next run. Can anyone give me suggestions to get this to work?

I tried to run it with axis = 0 like the other np operations but that didn't work. and running it normally has issues because the unique name is a string instead of a float. But it also doesn't make sense to just get the 3 values because I'm not trying to compare the numbers in the list, I'm wanting to compare the numbers vertically but also be able to remove the entire row if it doesn't fit the parameters.

Comment: So far what I have been trying is assigning standard deviation and the mean separately and generating a list of the values that are within standard deviation, but now I'm trying to remove the elements of the original list if the values of this specific IDX don't match the original list. It just seems more complicated than what it should be, I was wondering if there was already a preset way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!! I ended up making two different functions, one that performs standard deviation and returns a list of the values on the specific index that fit within two standard deviations.

```
import NumPy as np
import statistics

def std_filter(list, idx):  # [[number,number,number], [number, number,number]...]
idx_pool = []
float_idx_pool = np.array(idx_pool, dtype=np.float32)

for element in list:
    item = element[idx]
    if isinstance(item, str) == True:
        print("item in element must be an int or float")
        break
    idx_pool.append(item)
float_idx_pool = np.append(float_idx_pool, idx_pool)

standard_deviation = statistics.stdev(idx_pool)
element_mean = [np.mean(float_idx_pool, axis=0)]

final_list = [x for x in idx_pool if (x > np.subtract(element_mean, 2 * standard_deviation))]
final_list = [x for x in final_list if (x < np.add(element_mean, 2 * standard_deviation))]

return final_list
```

I have the original list run through another function to determine if the number matches any in the correct list. It just needs to specify the specific index.

```
def remove_nested_with_idx(List_main, List_keep, list_main_idx):
# function sistructive, making sure to copy
list_to_modify = List_main.copy()
# runs through each element in specific idx and compares it to specific list
for elem_in_list in List_main:
    item = elem_in_list[list_main_idx]
    # checks item to see if value is in List_keep
    if item not in List_keep:
        list_to_modify.remove(elem_in_list)
return list_to_modify
```

If anyone can figure out a better way to do this please let me know.